# Drive failed in RAID, other drive has SMART errors. Which to trust?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, mdadm, smart

I've had a RAID1 setup running in my machine for a couple of years, and recently the array has become degraded. Looking at mdadm information, it looks like the one drive has failed, but when I look at SMART info, the *other* drive has had errors. I'm not sure which to trust.

If I'm reading the output of `sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0` correctly, `/dev/sda1` has failed, and `/dev/sdb1` is still in the array, and can be trusted.

```
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Sat Jan  5 01:18:40 2013
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 2930133824 (2794.39 GiB 3000.46 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 2930133824 (2794.39 GiB 3000.46 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 1
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Thu Aug  6 20:33:11 2015
          State : clean, degraded 
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 1
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           Name : storm:0  (local to host storm)
           UUID : 98b434f9:54d5c413:1acc4033:8ad34365
         Events : 8388

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       0        0        0      removed
       1       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1
```

However, after running a short SMART self-test on both drives, `/dev/sda` has no issues, but `/dev/sdb` is showing things like this:

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     ST3000DM001-1CH166
...
Local Time is:    Thu Aug  6 20:45:02 2015 EDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

...

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 12 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)

...

Error 12 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 21016 hours (875 days + 16 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 00 ff ff ff 4f 00   8d+20:05:45.525  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 00   8d+20:05:45.525  SET FEATURES [Reserved for Serial ATA]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00   8d+20:05:45.525  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00   8d+20:05:45.524  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 46 00 00 00 a0 00   8d+20:05:45.524  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]

...


SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     21129         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     18418         -
# 3  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      1860         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1855         -

...
```

Full output can be found here: http://pastebin.com/jDN0muXk

Should I trust mdadm saying that `/dev/sda` is bad, and I should trust `/dev/sdb`, or should I trust SMART in `/dev/sdb` having errors, and `/dev/sda` still being in good shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try both!  The one that actually has the data on it and you can read it is the one to trust!

Honestly, I don't think the SMART errors, unless they're pretty severe, will discredit the drive.  I would go with /dev/sdb on this one, but replace both drives ASAP!